# java.mail does not attach files, Android. Error: IOException

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, react-native

I can not attach a file to an attachment.

```
ERROR: IOException while sending message
```

Without attachments sends excellent
I check File.exists() is true

I tried many methods. Not one does not work. The same result

```
...
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailhost);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
Transport transport = session.getTransport();

msg.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
msg.setSubject(subject);

MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
part.setText(body);


String file = new String("/sdcard/DCIM/2.jpg");
FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(file);
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName());

if (new File(file).exists()) Log.e("sendMail", "file exists");

multipart.addBodyPart(part);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);

msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));

transport.connect(mailhost, username, password);
transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

**solved** the problem in android permissions and

```
attachmentPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

*image/jpeg* smtp server complains of spam :)

Comment: `I check File.exists() is true` I dont see such code. Please add it at the right place in your post.

Comment: code with try catch block and try to find where the code make problem

Comment: File.exists() added to code.

Comment: Hasib Akter  IOException while sending message